# Angular material reactive forms. Disable checkbox depending on drop down selection

Tags: angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have some code that disables the checkbox depending on the drop down selection. I now also want to force uncheck depending on selection from drop down.

html:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="permissions">
<th mat-header-cell class="text-center" *matHeaderCellDef>Permissions</th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let p" class="text-center">
     <mat-select [formControl]="p.item.permissionsControl">
        <mat-option [value]="permissionOptions.NoAccess">No Access</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="permissionOptions.ReadOnly">Read Only</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="permissionOptions.Modify">Modify</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="permissionOptions.Confirm">Confirm</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="permissionOptions.Full">Full</mat-option>
        </mat-select> 
</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="canConfirmOwnChanges">
    <th mat-header-cell class="text-center" *matHeaderCellDef>Can Confirm Own Changes</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let p" class="text-center">
        
        <span *ngIf="p.item.permissionsControl.value == permissionOptions.Confirm || p.item.permissionsControl.value == permissionOptions.Full"> 
        
            <mat-checkbox [disabled]="false" [formControl]="p.item.canConfirmOwnChangesControl"></mat-checkbox>
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="p.item.permissionsControl.value == permissionOptions.NoAccess || p.item.permissionsControl.value == permissionOptions.ReadOnly || p.item.permissionsControl.value == permissionOptions.Modify">
            <mat-checkbox  [disabled]="true" [formControl]="p.item.canConfirmOwnChangesControl"></mat-checkbox>
        </span>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Adding [checked]="false" does not work here.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by subscribing to valueChanges on the FormControl for the dropdown and then enable / disable and set the value on the checkbox FormControl